# Не пробрасывается порт

Tags: роутер, порт

подскажите пожалуйста, кто знает, что я не так сделал, роутер HG8245H5 , нужно пробросить порт 27015, вроде бы добавил правило, но когда проверяю,например, на "yougetsignal.com" , то пишет - закрыт, почему? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не указан внешний адрес и внешний порт, те что видны в Интернете.

Comment: команда netstat -a, показывает кучу всего,как узнать какой мне порт нужен оттуда, и куда их воодить, тут же нет полей для этих данных? заранее благодарю

Comment: Адрес который провайдер выдает, белый статический или динамический или вообще серый?